# Match all gray-scale colors in hex

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a file with some hex colors:

```
.. #101010   ..   match
.. #a2a2a2   ..   match
.. #abcd10   ..   do not match
.. #000000   ..   match
.. #111222   ..   do not match
.. #ffffff   ..   match
.. #3b3b3b   ..   match
.. #121012   ..   do not match
.. #fff      ..   match
.. #aba      ..   do not match
```

How to select all hex-colors which `red`, `green` and `blue` values are the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
#([a-fA-F\d]{1,2})\1{2}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS5iE0/1)

`\1` is back-reference of first 1 or 2 digits after `#`

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
#                  # Match a literal hash or #
([a-fA-F\d]{1,2})  # Match 1 or 2 hex digit and group it as captured group #1
\1{2}              # Match 2 more occurrences of back-reference \1
\b                 # Assert a word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this works in vim:

## ([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])\1\1